# Debugging Groovy scripted pipelines in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm developing Jenkins pipelines as Groovy scripts (scripted pipelines, not declarative), and having a real hard time. Jenkins is always very generic regarding syntax/semantic errors, outputting stacks like below:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: caughtError for class: groovy.lang.Binding
at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
at
```

So I have to figure where the error is completely by myself, inspecting line per line of code.
Is there a better way to  debug it? What you guys use to do?

Comment: I figured out one of the main problems was my `catch` block, at the end of the script. You must handle exceptions properly.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have seen this post, http://notes.asaleh.net/posts/debugging-jenkins-pipeline/
Which describe how to debug a groovy script for jenkins pipeline.
it's clearly describe the steps how to do it.